# Why adding an image to a table cell cause it to put padding around it

Tags: html, css, image

Why adding an image to a table cell cause it to put padding around it

I have the following HTML code which displays correctly:

```
<tr style="background: #FFFFFF">
    <td style="width: 300px; background: #FF0000; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <!--<img border="0" name="Cont_206" src="uly/travelmed.jpg" alt="" />-->
    </td>
    <td style="width: 277px;">
        <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">If you are planning to visit less developed nations or regions, Travel Medicine and Infectious Disease specialists <strong><a name="Forni_1" xt="SPCLICKSTREAM" href="http://aspx?id=367" target="_blank">Dr. Art</a></strong> and <strong><a name="Kesh_1" xt="SPCLICKSTREAM" href="http://provider.aspx?id=368" target="_blank">Dr. Sa</a></strong> provide an essential medical service to protect your health.</span></span></p>
        <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: rgb(99, 187, 77);"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;"><strong>Why Their Service is Unique<br />
        </strong><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Our travel medicine services are like an insurance policy,&rdquo; says Dr. Kesh.</span></span></span></span></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Displays:

[image]

When I uncomment the image which is 290px in width, it takes up more space than normal and squeezes the cell next to it:

[image]

How do I fix it so there aren't extra spaces around the image?

Comment: You should refrain from inline style. Instead, consider using a style sheet. (This also helps with debugging.)

Comment: Set a static width for the column that contains the image.

Comment: I did. `<td style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">`

Comment: Doesn't do that for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zqA9a/

Comment: Can u create a fiddle. It will easy for debugging

Comment: More important, don't use tables to format pages. Tables are for data, not page layout. Use a `div`-based layout; it works a lot better for images and whatnot.

Comment: Ouch! looks like it can be an IE issue... Chrome I just checked my code and it works fine :/ How do I fix for IE8?

Comment: I definitely agree but the template software I am using only allows table and not DIV :/

Answer (score 1):

If you want the width of your table to be fixed and not addapting to content, you must set this behavior to your table element. In CSS you do it with table-layou and value fixed .
your code becomes basicly :

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
<tr style="background: #FFFFFF">
    <td style="width: 300px; background: #FF0000; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <!--<img border="0" name="Cont_206" src="uly/travelmed.jpg" alt="" />-->
    </td>
    <td style="width: 277px;">
        <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">If you are planning to visit less developed nations or regions, Travel Medicine and Infectious Disease specialists <strong><a name="Forni_1" xt="SPCLICKSTREAM" href="http://aspx?id=367" target="_blank">Dr. Art</a></strong> and <strong><a name="Kesh_1" xt="SPCLICKSTREAM" href="http://provider.aspx?id=368" target="_blank">Dr. Sa</a></strong> provide an essential medical service to protect your health.</span></span></p>
        <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: rgb(99, 187, 77);"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial;"><strong>Why Their Service is Unique<br />
        </strong><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Our travel medicine services are like an insurance policy,&rdquo; says Dr. Kesh.</span></span></span></span></p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Best is of course to put the style within your css file and avoid the style attributes. style will be the sames.

**DEMO** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJabz

Comment: In Chrome and FF it works fine but in IE8 the contents on the right is still squeezed toward the right.